# Entity Framework CodeFirst with many-to-many relationship via DataAnnotations

Tags: c#, entity-framework, many-to-many, ef-code-first, data-annotations

I am trying to create a many-to-many relationship between the following objects:

```
public class Classified{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}    
    public string details {get;set;}
    public ICollection<ClassifiedRating> Ratings {get;set;}  
}

public class User{
    [Key]
    public int Id {get;set;}
    public string Name {get;set;}
}

public class ClassifiedRating{
    [Key]
    public User Rater {get;set;}
    [Key]
    public Classified Classified {get;set;}
    public int rating {get;set;}
}
```

I receive the following errors when I run it:

```
One or more validation errors were detected during model generation:

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntityType: : EntityType 'ClassifiedRating' 
has no key defined. Define the key for this EntityType.

\tSystem.Data.Entity.Edm.EdmEntitySet: EntityType: EntitySet 'ClassifiedRating'
 is based on type 'RateUser' that has no keys defined.
```

(the "\t"'s are appearing in the error message as well, though I doubt it is relevant, it's kinda weird....)

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know, the key must be either a string, integer type, or a Guid object.  Basically this forces you to always have an artificial key for every class you want stored, but generally this is a good idea.  Try giving `ClassifiedRating` an integer key instead of trying to use class `User`.

Comment: Yup this is correct, a PK in the DB must be on an actual column, and the User property in your model is navigation only

Comment: thank you, i didn't know that. it works, now another bug ill figure out

Answer (score 1):

`ClassifiedRating` should look like this:

```
public class ClassifiedRating
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public int RaterId { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public int ClassifiedId { get; set; }

    public User Rater {get;set;}
    public Classified Classified { get; set; }

    public int rating { get; set; }
}
```

Naming conventions will detect the two parts of the composite primary key as a foreign key to the other two tables and you should get the two one-to-many relationships you need in your model.

Comment: I will used `virtual` for `User` and `Classified` objects